# Report Hash Progress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hash, md5

I am learning the MD5 hash values of the files through the code I have provided below. However, as the file size grows, the calculation takes a long time as well. I want to reflect this calculation on a progress bar object, but I have no idea.

I want something like this;

```
progressBar.Value = mD5.ComputedBytes;
progressBar.Maximum = mD5.TotalBytesToCompute;
```

How to make this?

Code;

```
public static string getMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
    string str = "";
    using (MD5 mD5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        { str = BitConverter.ToString(mD5.ComputeHash(fileStream)).Replace("-", string.Empty); fileStream.Close(); }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting (from the MD5 Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) that _"The CMU Software Engineering Institute considers MD5 essentially 'cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use'"_.  You won't be able to show "progress" unless you can break the operation up into chunks (for example, if you were hashing 5 files, you could show 20% progress after each file).  You can pop up an indefinite progress bar to show that work is happening, but you really can't show specific progress

Comment: `HashAlgorithm` gives you the ability to hash data in chunks using `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock` methods. In the other hand, `Stream` class also allows you to read data in chunks asynchronously.

Considering these facts, you can create a method to get a stream as input and then read stream in chunks and then for each chuck hash it and report the progress (percentage for example) by calculating bytes read.

Comment: The solution is not limited to MD5, so you can use it for other hash algorithms as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`HashAlgorithm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) gives you the ability to hash data in chunks using [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and [`TransformFinalBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) methods. In the other hand, [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) class also allows you to read data in chunks asynchronously.

Considering these facts, you can create a method to get a stream as input and then read stream in chunks and then for each chuck hash it and report the progress (number of bytes processes) by calculating bytes read.

**ComputeHashAsync**

Here I've created a `ComputeHashAsync` extension method for `HashAlgorithm` class. It accepts:

- `stream`: input `Stream` to compute hash.
- `cancellationToken`: an optional `CancellationToken` which can be used to cancel the operation
- `progress`: an optional instance of `IProgress<long>` which receives the progress report (number of bytes processed).
- `buggerSize`: an optional buffer size for reading data. The default id 1024*1024 bytes.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

```
public static class HashAlgorithmExtensions {
    public static async Task<byte[]> ComputeHashAsync(
        this HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Stream stream,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken),
        IProgress<long> progress = null,
        int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024) {
        byte[] readAheadBuffer, buffer, hash;
        int readAheadBytesRead, bytesRead;
        long size, totalBytesRead = 0;
        size = stream.Length;
        readAheadBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        readAheadBytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(readAheadBuffer, 0, 
           readAheadBuffer.Length, cancellationToken);
        totalBytesRead += readAheadBytesRead;
        do {
            bytesRead = readAheadBytesRead;
            buffer = readAheadBuffer;
            readAheadBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            readAheadBytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(readAheadBuffer, 0,
                readAheadBuffer.Length, cancellationToken);
            totalBytesRead += readAheadBytesRead;

            if (readAheadBytesRead == 0)
                hashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            else
                hashAlgorithm.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, buffer, 0);
            if (progress != null)
                progress.Report(totalBytesRead);
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        } while (readAheadBytesRead != 0);
        return hash = hashAlgorithm.Hash;
    }
}
```

**Example 1 - Update ProgressBar**

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var hash = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open))
    {
        bytes = await hash.ComputeHashAsync(fs,
            progress: new Progress<long>(i =>
            {
                progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = i;
                }));
            }));
        MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty));
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Cancelling task after 1 second**

```
try
{
    var s = new CancellationTokenSource();
    s.CancelAfter(1000);
    byte[] bytes;
    using (var hash = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open))
        {
            bytes = await hash.ComputeHashAsync(fs,
                cancellationToken: s.Token,
                progress: new Progress<long>(i =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        progressBar1.Value = i;
                    }));
                }));

            MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty));
        }
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Operation canceled.");
}
```

**Creating a large file for test**

```
var f = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "temp.log");
File.Delete(f);
using (var fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Seek(1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.WriteByte(0);
    fs.Close();
}
```

---

<sub>*Note:* The implementation of computing hash in chunks, is taken from a blog [post](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=144) by Alexandre Gomes, then I changed the code to make it `async` and support `CancellationToken` and `IProgress<long>`.</sub>

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you very much for your reply. I'm not sure exactly how to use this code. Could you help me a bit? I created a "Hash.cs" named class for the first code and placed the lines of code in the class, but some lines seemed to be incorrect.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. About using the code, just create an empty `.cs` code file and then copy my code in the file. Then everything should be fine and wherever you create an instance of your hash algorithm like `md5`, it will have a `ComputeHashAsync` method.

Comment: This is how [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) work in C#.

Comment: I created "Hash.cs" file and copied your code. And then, the following errors occurred.

1: https://ibb.co/wNdqV36
2: https://ibb.co/J7jNj2c
3: https://ibb.co/4NRXZ22

How to fix these errors?

Comment: It seems you are missing `using System;`

Comment: `using System;` is not using. I added this, and nothing changed.

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't support async/await.

Comment: Which version is required for this?

Comment: Okay, I upgraded this project's version. Class error fixed. Now, how to use this method with parameter? I want to return the MD5 value, and I need to one example. :)

https://ibb.co/SR78Fj6

Comment: I've shared two examples ;)

Comment: Ohh okay okay, I understood and fixed all problems. Just configured progressBar.Maximum to fs.Length. Now, everything working successfully! Thank you soo much. :)

Comment: Is this line (`readAheadBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];`) necessary inside of the do-loop? The size never changes.

Comment: Hello again! Excuse me, again me. I'm getting this error when fetching file MD5, how to fix this error?

Error: A closed file cannot be accessed.

Program: https://ibb.co/Y2Hgn73

Method: https://ibb.co/yf9RvLF

Usage: https://ibb.co/JqKYyHV

Where is the problem?

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure, but passing `fs.Length` to the `Invoke` is not good idea, because it may be accessed while the fs is closed. Instead, put it in a variable and pass the variable.